# Open play store or app store when user press branch.io link for particular url

Tags: android, react-native, app-store, deep-linking, branch.io

So currently we are using branch.io for our app. If the user clicks on the branch.io link then we open our website first then we show our own button "Open in App" and if the user clicks on it then we navigate him to the play store/app store. This is how our flow.

Now we need to do one more configuration for some particular URL. When I say particular URL it means app invitation deep-link (branch.io link)URL. So when a UserA invites his friend UserB by sending him a particular URL. And UserB clicks on the particular URL. Then we want to open a play store/app store if UserB does not has our app. If UserB has the app then just simply open the app.

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: Can you share the exact issue you are facing configuring this?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your question. I updated the description please read it again.